# terminal interrupts forking printf()

Tags: c, linux, fork

I want to do a little program in C.
Its all about forking processes and executing linux programs.
The process hierachy should look like this

```
    P1
 P2    P3
         P4
```

So P2 and P3 are children of P1 and P4 is a child of P3!
But i always have the problem that the father process died before the other processes were ready. So the output in terminal is interrupted by the terminal itself O: I have to click enter to exit it! (But not everytime o.O)

My code looks like this:

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{

    pid_t kind1, kind2, kind3,hilf; 
    kind1 = fork();
    if(kind1==0)
    {

        printf("Prozess 2:%d--%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
    }
    else
    {
        kind2 = fork();
        if(kind2==0)
        {
            hilf=getpid();          
            fork();
            if(getpid()==hilf)
            {                       
                printf("Prozess 3:%d--%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
                wait();
            }
            else
            {
                printf("Prozess 4:%d--%d\n",getpid(),getppid());
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Prozess 1:%d\n",getpid());
            wait();
            return 0;
        }
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The printf's are going to be replaced by various exec* functions!
Please tell me how to use the wait properly so my problems won't occur!

Comment: It works on my pc. everytime it prints `Prozess 1:3705
Prozess 2:3706--3705
Prozess 3:3707--3705
Prozess 4:3708--3707
`

Comment: `wait` in shell waits for all children. `wait()` in C waits for one child at a time. You need to `#include <sys/wait.h>` so the compiler tells you that you are calling `wait()` without the necessary parameter, and you need to wrap `wait()` in a loop. You also need to fix your compilation options so that you don't let that mistake slip past you again: `gcc -O3 -g -std=c11 -Wall -Wextra -Wmissing-prototypes -Wstrict-prototypes -Wold-style-definition -Werror` is roughly what I use (sometimes `-std=c99`; depends on which version of GCC I'm using).

Answer (score 2):

The idiomatic way of writing code like this is to

1. Use the return value of `fork()`. If it's greater than zero, this is the pid of the child process, and you are executing in the parent process.
2. Use a member of the `waitpid()` family in the parent process to wait for the child process to end.

Answer (score -1):

Use a `pipe` to synchronise exiting.

```
int main() {

int syncpipe[2];
pipe(syncpipe);

......

close(syncpipe[1]); // I am done
char buffer;
read(syncpipe[0], &buffer, 1); // wait for all others

return 0;
}
```

Comment: No need for that at all.